# "Diménticatelo" oppure "Dimenticàtelo"?

Tags: verbs

Mi è capitato di recente di imbattermi in questa frase :

> Lo zio Giovanni? ***Dimenticatelo***, visto che non risponde da anni alle nostre lettere.

In quel caso, la frase era parte di un racconto più lungo e quindi l'interpretazione della forma verbale era semplificata da informazioni precedenti.

In realtà però si tratta di una espressione decisamente ambigua, almeno nella forma scritta, in quanto il soggetto del verbo *dimenticatelo* dipende da dove cade l'accento. Se infatti leggiamo ***diménticatelo***, stiamo suggerendo ad una seconda persona singolare di dimenticarsi di qualcuno; se al contrario leggiamo ***dimenticàtelo***, lo stesso suggerimento viene dato ad almeno due persone (seconda persona plurale).

A questo punto vorrei sapere se esiste una metodologia per identificare il corretto significato di una frase simile quando la troviamo in forma scritta (anche perché gli accenti che io ho indicato non sono mai presenti), oppure se l'unica maniera è avere un contesto a cui far riferimento.

Answer (score 15):

Sono forme omografe e di funzione grammaticale identica, se non ci sono appigli di contesto o di eventuali concordanze nella frase è impossibile stabilire a priori quale intendesse l'autore.

In effetti, un revisore coscienzioso dovrebbe segnalare il problema se la forma risulta ambigua nella frase, e non a caso più di una volta credo di aver trovato scritta la forma in questione disambiguata esplicitamente con accenti tonici.

Comment: confermo, nel caso il contesto renda la frase ambigua gli accenti tonici sono spesso presenti

Comment: Dopo le vostre affermazioni circa la presenza degli accenti tonici per distinguere in italiano tra vocaboli omografi ho iniziato a farci attenzione nei vari testi che mi capitavano (giornali, riviste, libri, materiale pubblicitario); devo però purtroppo confermare che di accenti usati per tale scopo non ho trovato traccia. Evidentemente abbiamo accesso a generi diversi di testo, oppure sono pochi i redattori che si pongono il problema.